Resetting my current sense transformer
I have a 1:100 (11 µH secondary inductance) current sense transformer. My primary side input voltage is 800 V and the current is 5 A, Fsw= 100 kHz. I have good ole diode and reset resistor to reset my secondary side transformer during turn off.
How do I calculate my reset resistor value? What would be my Vout?


What's your max duty cycle?

Have you tried simulating your circuit and using a bridge rectified output to feed your burden resistor.

max duty cycle is about 0.45. Yes but simulation does not give the magnetizing inductance.

Then you have the remaining 55 % available to you to produce enough negative Vt product to cancel out the positive Vt product you produced on the 45 % on cycle.
